# WebClient: exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer

Tags: kotlin, jaxb, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

I using spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.7

I have the below config of webclient to call soap web services

```
@Bean
fun webClientXml(): WebClient {
    val httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 100000).doOnConnected {
            it.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(100))
            it.addHandlerLast(WriteTimeoutHandler(100))
        }.resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)

    val exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs {
        it.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024)
        it.customCodecs().register(Jaxb2SoapEncoder())
        it.customCodecs().register(Jaxb2SoapDecoder())
    }.build()

    return WebClient.builder()
        .codecs { it.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024) }
        .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies).build()
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    webclient:
      max-in-memory-size: 512MB
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 512MB
```

config of Jaxb2SoapDecoder

```
class Jaxb2SoapDecoder : Jaxb2XmlDecoder() {

    override fun setMaxInMemorySize(byteCount: Int) {
        super.setMaxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024)
    }

    @Throws(DecodingException::class)
    override fun decode(dataBuffer: DataBuffer, targetType: ResolvableType, @Nullable mimeType: MimeType?, @Nullable hints: MutableMap<String, Any>?): Any {
        .....
    }
    
}
```

config of Jaxb2SoapEncoder

```
class Jaxb2SoapEncoder : Encoder<Any> {

    private fun encode(value: Any, bufferFactory: DataBufferFactory): Flux<DataBuffer> {
        return Mono.fromCallable {
            var release = true
            val buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(1000000000)
            .....
        }.flux()
```

}
}

when i invoke an api, i have the below error

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException:
> 200 OK from POST
> xxxxxxxxx;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded
> limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144